# How do I loop through each tag inside of a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a function which has a for loop that runs through each tag in a specific div. for example, here would be the div:

```
<div>
 <input id="inputid"></input>
 <a id="aid"></a>
 <div id="divid"></div>
</div>
```

is there a "for each tag in x" kind of function in javascript that would allow me to loop through it? keep in mind that I can't do this in jquery and each tag will likely be different, as shown above.

Comment: why can't you do it in jQuery?

Comment: part of the benefit of this project to me is to learn javascript as an entry point to .net languages or java and jquery is too dissimilar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want all elements that are contained within a div (including children of children, etc...) and you want only elements (not other types of nodes) and you want it to work in all browsers then you can use `getElementsByTagName("*")` like this:

```
var allTags = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = allTags.length; i < len; i++) {
    // allTags[i] is an element within the container object
    // allTags[i].id is the id of the element (if there is one)
}
```

`document.getElementById('container')` is just some means to get the container element - you can use any method that is appropriate to get the containing parent element.

`getElementsByTagName("*")` can take a wildcard as shown so it returns all elements contained within the node and it can be called on any element to retrieve elements only from within that containing element.

Comment: one last bit, if you have the time, could I use if (allTags[i].id != null){} to find out if the tag has an id?

Comment: @CaptainDando - You can use `if (allTags[i].id) {}` to check for a valid id.  It may be `undefined` or an empty string if not present and this will check for either.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var div = getElementById('containerDivId');
for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    console.log(div.childNodes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I you want to iterate through ALL fo the tags off ALL the children (not just first level-children)

```
jQuery(element).find('*').each( function (index,value) { 
        $.each(value.attributes, function(i, attrib){
        var name = attrib.name,
           value = attrib.value;
         // do whatever you wann do 
         console.log({ attributeName : name, attributeValue: value});
      });
});
```

Comment: was thinking that " keep in mind that I can't do this in jquery " referes to fact tat Captain Dando could not find a way to do this in jQuery. my bad

Comment: Sorry toske, this would be a good answer, but I'm after javascript specifically. thanks for your time anyways